# How to share a kafka connector and its configuration between multiple services in Quarkus?

Tags: apache-kafka, quarkus

I've got the following project structure:

```
project
  - serviceA
  - serviceB
  - serviceC
  - serviceD
```

And I would like to have a common kafka connector in all the project services. Something like this:

```java
public class CommonProcessor {
    private final CommonService commonService;

    public CommonProcessor(final CommonService commonService) {
        this.commonService= commonService;
    }

    @Incoming("channel-name")
    public CompletionStage<Void> process(final Message<CommonMessage> message) {
        final CommonMessage commonMessage = message.getPayload();

        commonService.commonMethod(commonMessage.getAttribute());

        return message.ack();
    }
}
```

With its corresponding configuration:

```
mp.messaging.incoming.channel-name.connector=smallrye-kafka
mp.messaging.incoming.channel-name.topic=channel-name
mp.messaging.incoming.channel-name.value.deserializer=foo.bar.CommonDeserializer
```

**How could I share this CommonProcessor (and its configuration) between all services?**

Can I put it in a common jar and add it as a dependency in all services? I've tried this option but it does not work because of the configuration. When starting the service with the dependency it says `Impossible to bind mediators, some media
tors are not connected: [foo.bar.CommonProcessor#process]`

Can it be done through an extension? In this case, I have the same question, how can I share the configuration in `application.properties`?

Comment: You would need to "jandex" the project containing CommonProcessor. However, unfortunately, the config would need to be duplicated. 

About jandex, adding this plugin to your mavne pom should work: https://github.com/smallrye/smallrye-mutiny/blob/master/pom.xml#L215-L227

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've already done what you suggest. I would like to avoid config duplication. Is there a way to register mediators programmatically? I mean, would it be possible to have an extension exposing `CommonProcesor` and `CommonService` as beans and at the same time register the mediator for `channel-name` without using a config file?

Comment: What you can do is exposing a ConfigSource with these properties: https://www.phillip-kruger.com/post/microprofile_config/

Comment: Thanks again for your answer. That is exactly what I have finally done. I was inspired by the quarkus yaml extension.